# Proving $\mathbb{Z}[i]^{\times}$ is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have no idea how to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[i]^{\times}$ is finite (unit group of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$).
I don't know any theorem and never studied properties of unit groups, so I don't even know where to start here.
This fact fact appeared to me as an example while I was studying modules.
Any help or hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks. And, like I said, I REALLY don't know where to start, I think I never proved that a group is finite in my life.

Comment: Consider norm function $N: \mathbb Z[i] \rightarrow \mathbbZ$, $N(a+bi) = a^2 + b^2$... Have you heard of this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\frac{1}{a+bi}=\frac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2}$.  If $a,b\in \mathbb Z$, when is this still in $\mathbb Z[i]$?

Comment: Here is an alternative hint.  Define $N(\alpha)=\alpha \overline{\alpha}$.  Then $N(\alpha)$ is real, and $N(\alpha\beta)=N(\alpha)N(\beta)$.  What happens if $\alpha\beta=1$?